# Requesting a variable when user login in

Tags: asp-classic, dreamweaver

I have a login form on page one in for user login, and on the login form i have 3 textfield namely email,password and code . when a user enters the right credentials and also enters his code the login will be successful. What i do on the page two is to request the code which the users enters with Request.Form("Code") which i assign to a textfield on page2. But when you enter the right crenditals and with the code i'm not able to recieve the code on page 2 in the textfield.

PAGE 1

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="Connections/sample.asp" -->
<%
' *** Validate request to log in to this site.
MM_LoginAction = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
If Request.QueryString <> "" Then MM_LoginAction = MM_LoginAction + "?" + Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString)
MM_valUsername = CStr(Request.Form("email"))
If MM_valUsername <> "" Then
  Dim MM_fldUserAuthorization
  Dim MM_redirectLoginSuccess
  Dim MM_redirectLoginFailed
  Dim MM_loginSQL
  Dim MM_rsUser
  Dim MM_rsUser_cmd

  MM_fldUserAuthorization = ""
  MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "page2.asp"
  MM_redirectLoginFailed = "error.asp"

  MM_loginSQL = "SELECT email, password"
  If MM_fldUserAuthorization <> "" Then MM_loginSQL = MM_loginSQL & "," & MM_fldUserAuthorization
  MM_loginSQL = MM_loginSQL & " FROM dbo.profile WHERE email = ? AND password = ?"
  Set MM_rsUser_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
  MM_rsUser_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_viva_web_STRING
  MM_rsUser_cmd.CommandText = MM_loginSQL
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Parameters.Append MM_rsUser_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 200, 1, 100, MM_valUsername) ' adVarChar
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Parameters.Append MM_rsUser_cmd.CreateParameter("param2", 200, 1, 100, Request.Form("password")) ' adVarChar
  MM_rsUser_cmd.Prepared = true
  Set MM_rsUser = MM_rsUser_cmd.Execute

  If Not MM_rsUser.EOF Or Not MM_rsUser.BOF Then 
    ' username and password match - this is a valid user
    Session("MM_Username") = MM_valUsername
    If (MM_fldUserAuthorization <> "") Then
      Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = CStr(MM_rsUser.Fields.Item(MM_fldUserAuthorization).Value)
    Else
      Session("MM_UserAuthorization") = ""
    End If
    if CStr(Request.QueryString("accessdenied")) <> "" And false Then
      MM_redirectLoginSuccess = Request.QueryString("accessdenied")
    End If
    MM_rsUser.Close
    Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginSuccess)
  End If
  MM_rsUser.Close
  Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginFailed)
End If
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imgs/viva_icon.ico" /><style type="text/css">
.pagefit {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
textfields {
}
.textfield {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #030303;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.style1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form METHOD="POST" id="form1" name="form1" action="<%=MM_LoginAction%>">
  <table width="278" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="67"><p>Email</p></td>
      <td width="195"><label for="email"></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><label for="password"></label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Code</td>
      <td><label for="code"></label>
      <input type="text" name="code" id="code" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PAGE 2

```
<%

Dim req

req = Request.Form("code")

%>


  <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield2" value="<%=req%>" />
```

Comment: 1) this has nothing to do with Dreamweaver. It's an editor. It doesn't execute code. 2) Please add your FORM code in your question.

Comment: i used dreamweaver in developing this and this all my code

Comment: What you use to build your code is irrelevant. So where is your HTML input for the "code" field? It is not in your example - so either your example is incomplete or your code is failing because you are looking for a field that does not exist.

Comment: scroll through well code the html is included

Comment: You are using `Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginSuccess)` to go to page2, you will have to append the value of the `code`field to the redirect url to get it in page 2.

Comment: Also, consider the `Server.Transfer` method in place of `Response.redirect`

Comment: @ SearchAndResQ how do i do that? can you phrase it in my code for me cos i'm new in programming

Comment: in your code, find `Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginSuccess)` and replace it with `Server.Transfer("page2.asp")`.

Comment: i did it and it gave me and error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Server.Transfer'

Comment: Try this: `Response.Redirect(MM_redirectLoginSuccess & "?code="&Request.Form("code"))`

Comment: its able to pass it to the address bar but yet still i can't request it into a textfield

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57203/discussion-between-searchandresq-and-blay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm familiar with this code as it is Dreamweaver's "Log In User" Server Behavior. You're not able to get that code via "Request.Form" because the login is not POSTing the login data to the next page.

What happens when you use this code is it is creating the Sessions `"MM_Username"` and `"MM_UserAuthorization"` (if you use user levels).

What you can do (and I do this for many of my sites) is have it create an additional Session for your code if the log in is valid by adding in this line after the the `Session("MM_Username")` is set

```vb
 If Not MM_rsUser.EOF Or Not MM_rsUser.BOF Then 
' username and password match - this is a valid user
Session("MM_Username") = MM_valUsername
' Here is your new code session
Session("MM_code") = Request.Form("code")
```

Then, on the next page, to retrieve the code, simply enter:

```vb
<%=Session("MM_code")%>
```

I just tested this before posting and it works as it should. :)

Comment: Dreamweaver doesn't do anything special it just provides templates that you can follow (imho there not the best) just to be clear. You could write code like this in Classic ASP without even using Dreamweaver.

Comment: now what i'm trying to do is to  request another variable aside the Request.Form ("code"), the variable i want to request is ("mark_code"), (mark_code) is a textfield in the login form which i've added, please how do i do that?

Comment: Basically, just do the same as above. Add another Session under the MM_code one, name it something like MM_markcode, then Request.Form("mark_code"). Then on the next page, pull that data using the same structure as the MM_code except using this fields name (i.e. MM_markcode).